# Unhide column on an archived webpage

Tags: html

It was displayed yesterday so I know it can be done.

#### Misc Information including the current, not yet archived, page

The current webpage is https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/
The "New Recovered" column is hidden by default.
Columns are hidden or unhidden by clicking the "Columns" button.
Using Windows 10 1909 and Firefox.

#### Why I know it can be made visible

Yesterday, the following archived version from June 19 was viewed.
https://web.archive.org/web/20200619233630/https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/
The "New Recovered" column was visible, along with three other columns.
Today, as in the past, "New Recovered" is again hidden.

The question? How can they be made visible?

#### What I have tried

Tab to "Columns" button; tried every modifier key, ctrl+, Enter, right- and left-click...

#### How to see what I see

First visit the current page https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/
"New Recovered" column is not visible.
Click "Columns" and select "New Recovered" which is column 7.
(it is 6 in list because column 1 can't be hidden)

Now, open an archived page.  This is the one which had no hidden columns yesterday.
https://web.archive.org/web/20200619233630/https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/
Note the "New Recovered" column is not visible.
To prove the data has been captured:

- Select "Yesterday"
- Press "Ctrl+u" to see the "Page Source"
- Find (Ctrl+f) and find one of the following "New Recovered" values (96,845  10,942) World & USA
- Find "Columns" to see the list of available columns.  ("New Recovered" is column 7)
- Find again and to see that columns 7, 16-18 are set to false preventing being displayed.

Since "New Recovered" on the archived page somehow became visible yesterday. I know it can be done.

Comment: Question is rather specific. But i can't get what technology you use. HTML in tags is obviously too wide, and do not describe all logs you provided.

Comment: It would only allow me to select common key words and that was the only one that was close.

The technology.  Firefox, a web browser.
No logs are created because no error is generated.

The steps to see the exact issue I am trying to overcome are listed in the section, "How to see what I see"

PS.  I wouldn't have even thought it was possible to get that page to display a table column that was hidden when archived.  However, it happened, so it should be repeatable.

Thanks for responding.